# I have a UTC string and I want to convert it to UTC Date Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript, I have a JSON call that returns my UTC DateTimes as strings and I want to convert them to UTC Date objects.  Has anyone done this?  I do not want to go to local time at all.

Comment: please show the exact format of your strings

Comment: '2016-11-22T17:14:00'

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On any vaguely-modern browser, you just pass that into `Date` with a `"Z"` on the end:

```
var dt = new Date(yourString + "Z");
```

That format was defined for JavaScript in the ES5 specification in December 2009. The `"Z"` is important to ensure that the string is interpreted as UTC, not local time¹.

`Date` objects keep track of a specific instant in time, which is irrespective of timezone. If you use the `Date`'s `UTC` methods (`getUTCFullYear`, `getUTCMonths`, etc.), you'll access that instant in UTC. (If you use the non-UTC methods, you'll access it translated to local time.)

Example:

```js
var str = "2016-11-22T17:14:00";
var dt = new Date(str + "Z");
console.log("UTC string:");
console.log(dt.toUTCString());
console.log("Local string");
console.log(dt.toString());
console.log("Hours UTC:   " + dt.getUTCHours());
console.log("Hours local: " + dt.getHours());
```

---

Some people are getting confused thinking that adding the `Z` makes the `Date` object parse in local time. It does not. This is clear from the specification ([1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date), [2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse)) and easily disproven:

```js
// ISO string
const str = "2023-09-01T00:00:00.000";
// Parsing it as UTC
const d = new Date(str + "Z");
// Verifying it's the same thing
const isoStr = d.toISOString();
console.log(str + "Z" === isoStr); // true
// Hour is midnight, as in the string
console.log(d.getUTCHours() === 0); // true
```

The confusion is because of the nature of `Date` objects. They offer **two** APIs to the moment in time they represent:

- A "local time" API
- A UTC API

If you parse a string in UTC, and then print it in local time (for instance, via `toString`), you're converting from UTC to local time. That wasn't because of the parsing, that was because of using the local time API (`toString`).

If you want to parse the string and print it out with `toString` and get the same thing, you want to parse it as local time. To do that, **don't** put the `Z` on. If it's a date+time string, it'll parsed as local time. Here's an example:

```js
console.log(new Date("2023-09-01T00:00:00").toString());
```

Notice that `toString` (which works in local time) matches the input string — both say `00:00:00`.

Beware that date-only strings without any timezone are always parsed in UTC. From [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse):

> When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

You can see that here:

```js
console.log(new Date("2023-09-01").toString());
```

Notice how the output string doesn't have `00` for its hours (what it has instead will depend on your timezone). That's because it's exactly as though it had the `Z`. Date-only and date-and-time strings are parsed differently.

---

¹ There's a bit of history in regard to that. When the format was originally added to the ES5 specification, it was *supposed* to be a subset of ISO-8601, but the ES5 spec said that no timezone indicator meant UTC, whereas in ISO-8601, no timezone indicator means local time. That lead to inconsistent implementations, where some were true to the ES5 specification, and others were true to ISO-8601. The bug was fixed in the ES2015 specification in June 2015. Now JavaScript's date/time format really is a subset of ISO-8601, except that JavaScript's `Date` always has a time component (all the way down to milliseconds), while ISO-8601 has the concept that a value may only be as specific as it is precise. That is, `2016-11-22` in JavaScript is a specific date **and** time, but in ISO-8601, it's just the date (no time is implied). Consequently, the current (ES2016) JavaScript specification [says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format):

> When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

So `2016-11-22` is interpreted as 2016-11-22 at midnight UTC, but `2016-11-22T00:00:00` is interpreted as 2016-11-22 at midnight local time. Bizarre, but true. Of course, this latest language in the specification may not be correctly implemented by all implementations yet (I note that Chrome 54 gets it wrong, for instance).

Bottom line: You need that `"Z"` to ensure the string is parsed as UTC.

Comment: @seroth no, the Z stands for "Zulu time", another way of referring to UTC+0000

Comment: @seroth: As Alnitak said, the Z means UTC. Regarding your fiddle: Again, as I said in the answer, `Date` instances represent a point in time, irrespective of timezone, and it's *how you access* the data in the `Date` that determines whether you see it in local time or UTC. Your fiddle is using the default `toString`, which translates to local time. If you use `toUTCString` instead, you get the UTC information: https://jsfiddle.net/n9aqysq9/1/

Comment: For anyone finding this thread in 2023, @seroth is correct, adding the Z causes the Date object to convert to local time. Removing it keeps UTC.

Comment: @ryanovas - Please read the comments above, that's incorrect. It **parses** the date in UTC. (seroth was just confused, and they accepted the answer once this was explained). You're likely being tripped up by the fact that the `Date` object offers two APIs to the time value it holds: One that converts to local, and one that accesses UTC. I've updated the answer itself to include that explanation.

Comment: Perhaps under the hood it's behaving as you say, but in all practical purposes it is converted. If you log it, it shows the local timezone. If you use any of the methods other than `.toUTCString()` it shows the local timezone. If you are attempting to work with or display ISO with the regular `Date` functions you're out of luck. If you drop the Z, then it just slaps your local timezone info on the same timestamp it was given but nothing is converted when you use the functions. Which is a hacky solution for an annoying problem in the first place. It should only convert if you ask it to convert.

Comment: @ryanovas - Your issues are with the design of the `Date` object (which is quite bad), not with this answer. The question was "How do I parse this string in UTC?" That's what this answer answers. You seem to want "How do I make the `Date` object work reasonably?" -- a very different question, to which the answer is: If you (understandably) don't like how `Date` works, use a library or (not now but soon) use [`Temporal`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) (probably [`ZonedDateTime`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/zoneddatetime.html). JavaScript, like Java and...

Comment: ...C#, got this badly wrong the first time. Java and C# have shipped improvements. `Temporal` will be JavaScript's. The answer *isn't* to treat a UTC string as though it represented local time (by leaving off the `Z`) so `toString` seems to work in limited tests, because by doing that you're pretending the string represents local time. But that's likely to go wrong, because it *isn't* local time but you're applying local time's rules (DST and such) to it. Misusing the poor API of `Date` isn't a good idea.