# Convert string to date format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string value and i need to convert that string value to the following date format using javascript.

var strDate = "2016-11-20";

expected output is: 20-Nov-2016

How Can I change this?

Comment: There are [*many duplicates*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date+string).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A little workaround could be the following, but if you have to manipulate dates a lot, I strongly recommend you to use the Moment.js library:

https://momentjs.com/

```js
var strDate = "2016-11-20";
var utcDate = new Date(strDate).toUTCString();
var convertedDate= utcDate.substring(utcDate.lastIndexOf(", ") + 1, utcDate.lastIndexOf(" 00:"));
console.log(convertedDate.trim().replace(/\s/g, '-'));
```

Pay attention that the implementation of this method may change depending on the platform. Here from the official doc:

> The value returned by toUTCString() is a human readable string in the
>   UTC time zone. The format of the return value may vary according to
>   the platform. The most common return value is a RFC-1123 formatted
>   date stamp, which is a slightly updated version of RFC-822 date
>   stamps.

Comment: But its shows 20 Nov 2016 but the expectation is 20-Nov-2016

Comment: [*toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) is implementation dependent, it does not necessarily return the string in the required format.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing that out. Absolutely correct. Updated the answer to explain that as well.

Answer (score 0):

javascript have rich set of Date function e.g.:

new Date();

new Date(value);

new Date(dateString);

new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

also already answered here  : 
[Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

[I have a UTC string and I want to convert it to UTC Date Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768606/i-have-a-utc-string-and-i-want-to-convert-it-to-utc-date-object-in-javascript/40768745#40768745)

We can mark this question duplicate

Comment: If it's a duplicate, mark it, though I disagree with the one you've marked. There are many duplicates for reformatting a **string**. Please don't post comments as answers.